# What prettier/eslint rule dictates JSX tag contents on new line

Tags: javascript, jsx, eslint, prettier

Using prettier with ESLint integration. After a recent upgrade of the prettier package, all my files seem to have gone from

```
<div>{props.title}</div>
```

to

```
<div>
  {props.title}
</div>
```

effectively increasing the LOC count by a significant number. Can't seem to find what rule or behavior is causing this, or how to keep the old style. Any pointers?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. Check out this [demo](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAucAbAhgZ0wAgGIQQ5wAe8UAJrgEpzpgwB0AwhALYAO0CMOwAOlBw4ATggpwRACgCUfQcJz8YYmAFcRQqQsXCAPBQCWANwB8wDiIgdMjGIZio4AXz0B6I2Z3C5O54OcQABoQa3toTGRQLBhkADN0VEw4EIAjEXoAazgYAGUOekMoAHN4xOSQiggwMqSUkAArTBIAIQywbLz0NjgAGSK4ZBU1eog1GA5xgCZaipACkWSRZBBU9FSAT1RoYPmRIpgAdUMKGAALZAAOAAYQ5LZDIZERu6LipwBFNQh4WfqYdbHU4XJBTEIqdCGVBvVhsNjoFZQbi7NTJAAq60iSASdWcziAA). You might want to check if the `printWidth` is long enough.

Comment: Looks like this was a problem in 1.5.x, upgraded to latest and everything is fine and dandy now!

Comment: @hampusohlsson, can you please share the correct configuration?